# Need help reducing cognitive complexity of a function in JS

Tags: javascript

I have this object

```
hours: {
    Tuesday: { open: 8, close: 18 },
    Wednesday: { open: 8, close: 18 },
    Thursday: { open: 10, close: 20 },
    Friday: { open: 10, close: 20 },
    Saturday: { open: 8, close: 22 },
    Sunday: { open: 8, close: 20 },
    Monday: { open: 0, close: 0 },
  }
```

Witch stores the functioning hours of a place.

I am creating a function that, if called with no arguments, returns the schedule of the week. When you call it with a specific day of the week as an argument, it returns this day's schedule.

Here's my function:

```
function getSchedule(dayName) {
  const scheduleArr = Object.entries(hours);
  const returnedObj = {};
  if (typeof dayName === 'undefined') {
    scheduleArr.forEach((entries) => {
      if (entries[1].open === entries[1].close) returnedObj[entries[0]] = 'CLOSED';
      else {
        returnedObj[entries[0]] = `Open from ${entries[1].open}am until ${entries[1].close - 12}pm`;
      }
    });
    return returnedObj;
  }
  const weekDay = scheduleArr.find((element) => element[0] === dayName);
  if (weekDay[1].open === weekDay[1].close) {
    returnedObj[weekDay[0]] = 'CLOSED';
    return returnedObj;
  }
  returnedObj[weekDay[0]] = `Open from ${weekDay[1].open}am until ${weekDay[1].close - 12}pm`;
  return returnedObj;
}
```

It works, but for this project, the cognitive complexity allowed for a function is 5. The current cognitive complexity of the above function is 6.

I would appreciate it if anyone could help me to fit this requirement, with minimal changes to my current function.

Comment: What is your desired output? Please add in the question itself.\

Comment: This question could be suitable for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help), as long as (a) your code works as intended, (b) your code is real code, rather than example code, and (c) your code is included in the body of the question. If you wish for a peer review to improve all aspects of your code, please post it on Code Review.

Comment: Why use `Object.entries` to make things more complicated...? You literally turns a simple `hours[dayName]` into `Object.entries(hours).find(element => element[0] === dayName)`

Comment: Why with only minimal changes to your current function? If it could be much better with more changes, what do you have against that?  Also, why does it all have to be implemented in one function?  The part about _if called with no arguments, returns the schedule of the week. When you call it with a specific day of the week as an argument, it returns this day's schedule._ suggests at least creating separate `getScheduleOfWeek` and `getScheduleOfDay` functions

Comment: nothing against it, @Wyck . Just trying to fix this one problem. I am working on a project that has some strict rules, but thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is actually another good method of refactoring the code to make it more readable:

```js
function getSchedule(dayName) {
    const scheduleArr = Object.entries(hours);
        const returnedObj = {};
        let result={};

        scheduleArr.forEach((day) => {
            returnedObj[day[0]] = (day[1].open === day[1].close)
                ? 'CLOSED'
                : `Open from ${day[1].open}AM until ${day[1].close - 12}PM`;
        });


        if (typeof dayName !== 'undefined') {
                result[dayName] = returnedObj[dayName];
                return result;
        }
        return returnedObj;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"Cognitive complexity" is a bad measurement, and shouldn't be part of code analysis tools. Tools like Codeclimate are bad practice for this reason and should be avoided.

One way to refactor this function is to change it to only one return statement, and instead of mutating an object, just create it as needed. You can also reduce over the array instead of looping.

```js
function getSchedule(dayName) {
  const scheduleArr = Object.entries(hours);
  const weekDay = scheduleArr.find((element) => element[0] === dayName);
  let result;

  if (typeof dayName === 'undefined') {
    result = scheduleArr.reduce((result, entries) => ({
      ...result,
      [entries[0]]: entries[1].open === entries[1].close ?
        'CLOSED' :
        `Open from ${entries[1].open}am until ${entries[1].close - 12}pm`
      }),
      {});
  } else if (weekDay[1].open === weekDay[1].close) {
    result = { [weekDay[0]]: 'CLOSED'};
  } else {
    result = {
      [weekDay[0]]: `Open from ${weekDay[1].open}am until ${weekDay[1].close - 12}pm`
    };
  }
  return result;
};
```

Comment: I agree with your considerations. But this function is still with the cognitive complexity of 6.

Comment: There's no way to verify your criteria without guessing and checking, since it's not a real metric used for code analysis

Comment: sorry, I'm just using eslint. Here's how it is verified https://eslint.org/docs/rules/complexity

Comment: oh, you meant cyclomatic complexity, not "cognitive complexity"

Comment: that is kinda confusing because the eslint error message on VSCode points to "cognitive complexity" but the documentation says "cyclomatic complexity"

Answer (score 0):

For the case of getting the entire week's schedule, you can `map` over `Object.entries` and convert the result to an object with `Object.fromEntries`. For a single day, you only need to access the value of the property with `dayName` as the key; `Object.entries` and `Array#find` only makes it more complicated.

```js
const hours = {
    Tuesday: { open: 8, close: 18 },
    Wednesday: { open: 8, close: 18 },
    Thursday: { open: 10, close: 20 },
    Friday: { open: 10, close: 20 },
    Saturday: { open: 8, close: 22 },
    Sunday: { open: 8, close: 20 },
    Monday: { open: 0, close: 0 },
}

function getSchedule(dayName) {
  if(dayName === undefined) return Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(hours).map(([k, v]) => 
      [k, v.open === v.close ? 'CLOSED' : 
        `Open from ${v.open}am until ${v.close - 12}pm`]));
  return {[dayName]: 
    `Open from ${hours[dayName].open}am until ${hours[dayName].close - 12}pm`};
}
console.log(getSchedule());
console.log(getSchedule('Tuesday'));
```